# Get Minitab active instance instead of creating new instance

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, process, com, minitab

I am trying to automate `minitab` with my `C# program`. I am able to open new minitab window with this code.

```
    MtbApp = new Mtb.Application();
    MtbProj = MtbApp.ActiveProject;
    MtbUI = MtbApp.UserInterface;
    MtbUI.Visible = true;
```

This code creates new minitab object and open new minitab window.

Now, my problem is , I dont want to open new minitab window. I want to use the already opened window and execute commands in that. For this I do

```
MtbApp = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Mtb.Application") as Mtb.Application;
```

But it always throw exception

**Operation unavailable (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401E3 (MK_E_UNAVAILABLE))**

I searched on google for this and i found that `mtb` should be in `Running Object Table`. I dont know where `ROT` is and dont know how to add `mtb` in `ROT`.

I also tried by getting opened minitab window handle

```
    Process[] pr = Process.GetProcessesByName("Mtb");
    Process p = pr[0];
    int hwnd = (int)Process.GetProcessById(pr[0].Id).MainWindowHandle;
```

but i am not sure how to assign handle to MtbApp object as MtbApp handle is read only property.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks